# How to avoid highlighting when block commenting?

Tags: search, regular-expression, substitute

I'm running the command

```
:.,.5s/^/!&
```

to block comment a section of code, however, after running the command the editor highlights the first character in every line of the file. I guess this doesn't surprise me since those characters match the regex, but I thought this would be suppressed if I add a range.

Answer (score 3):

#### Standing on the shoulders of giants

I would highly recommend commenting plugin like [commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) (which I use), [Nerd Commenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter), [EnhCommentify](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=23), [tComment](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim), ..., [etc](http://vimawesome.com/?q=comment). There is no shame in using a plugin.

Comment: so far commentary is very useful, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

`:.,.5norm I!` is an alternative that doesn't use substitution.

By the way, you can shorten your original command like this:

```
:,.5s/^/!
```

,or like that:

```
:,+5s/^/!
```

Also, I don't know if you are aware of that but you can prepend your ex command with a count to automatically insert the right range:

```
6:s/^/!
```

gives:

```
:.,.+5s/^/!
```

And this is yet another way:

```
:s/^/!/6
```

But yeah, use commentary.

Answer (score 0):

After performing a search, you can hide the highlights by running

```
:noh
```

which is short for `:nohlsearch`.  After your next search, the highlights will re-appear.

I actually have this mapped to <kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd> so it's even easier to perform.

```
nmap <silent> <C-L> <C-L>:nohlsearch<CR>:match<CR>:diffupdate<CR>
```